# How do I install parmap package when ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parmap'

Tags: python, conda, spyder, numba

I just installed Spyder with miniconda (version 22.9.0) and several modules (numpy, seaborn...) (using Windows 10)
I also used the same process in the powershell to install the parmap and numba packages (both fail) with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge parmap
```

When I run my script starting with

```
import parmap
```

I get the following:
[image: error message]

When I use the conda list function in the powershell, I can see that parmap is installed. Here is an extract:

```
(spyder-cf) PS C:\Users\didie> conda list Spyder$
# packages in environment at C:\Users\didie\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.3.3           py310haa95532_0
(spyder-cf) PS C:\Users\didie> conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\didie\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
numba                     0.56.4          np1.21py3.10hd3205ba_g288a38bbd_0    numba
numpy                     1.22.3          py310hed7ac4c_2    conda-forge
pandas                    1.4.4           py310hd77b12b_0
parmap                    1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.1.2           py310h3a564e9_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.8.1           py310h7c00807_2    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.12.1               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spyder                    5.3.3           py310haa95532_0
spyder-kernels            2.3.3           py310haa95532_0
```

Other info if it could help:

```
(spyder-cf) PS C:\Users\didie> conda -V
conda 22.9.0
```

I'm not an expert (learning by copying) and would appreciate your help for both parmap and numba please...

Comment: The console example shows Python 3.8 is the interpreter, whereas the **spyder-cf**  environment shows Python 3.10 packages. Please ensure you are using the correct kernel.

Comment: I found where to change the python release with your help.
In the Spyder menu bar, click Tools, Preferences, Python interpreter, Use the following Python interpreter and select the one that matches your environment